# Intersection of triangle altitude feet with midpoint circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

While playing around with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831352/locus-using-euclidean-geometry) question, I seemed to find a relationship I wasn't aware of. A circle centered at the midpoint of a side of a triangle, and having that side as its diameter, intersects the feet of the altitudes from the endpoints of that side. See example below:

[image]

The circle centered at the midpoint of AC and having AC as its diameter, seems to intersect the feet E and D of the altitudes from points A and C.

I assume this is common knowledge, but couldn't immediately Google a proof. Can anyone show this is true?

Comment: Google for Thales

Comment: @Hagen: Just found the reference. Thanks.

Comment: It also follows from the property of right triangles that the length of the median drawn from the right-angle vertex is half the hypotenuse. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/240837) a *proof without words*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that, if $XZ$ is a diameter of a circle, and $Y$ is a point on the circle, $\angle XYZ = 90^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it that way: Pick two arbitrary points D and E on the circumference. They will face the diameter on a 90 degree angle.. Expend AD and CE to create a triangle. Then, AE and CD are altitudes of the triangle...