# $ABC$ is a triangle. Find the locus of $P$ if $PA^2 + PB^2 = PC^2$

Tags: geometry, locus

The exact question is

$ABC$ is a triangle. Find the locus of $P$ if $PA^2 + PB^2 = PC^2$.

I have solved similar questions in Coordinate geometry where coordinates of the sides were given and I know the locus is a line, but I'm not able to conlude anything in the general case.
I tried using,

$PA^2 + PB^2 + PC^2=GA^2+GB^2+GC^2+3PG^2$

But couldn't proceed further, I also tried to draw medians to AG from P but arrived at the same equation.

Comment: I asked the same question once and it has been answered. Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012674/find-the-locus-of-this-point-p

Comment: If it's the same question, just close it as a duplicate. If others don't agree with you, they will not vote to close the question and this allows people who want to close to do it faster.